# Phonegap Setup Cordova Error Create Error

Tags: android, cordova, installation

I am trying to get set up on a basic Hello World phonegap android application. I have installed and correctly configured the paths for ant, the java jdk, and the android sdk. However, when I attempt to run

```
create C:\Users\Shoes\Documents\Dev\Test com.codebundle.test Test
```

and cordova gave me the following error

```
Missing one of the following:
JDK: http://java.oracle.com
Android SDK: http://developer.android.com
Apache ant: http://ant.apache.org
```

I have tested that all the paths are setup correctly by trying

```
ant
adb
java
```

All worked fine, Please help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you type "android" what happens? You need to make sure that the $ANDROID_HOME/tools and $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools are both in your $PATH.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

Worked with a friend last night and his problem was the JRE was in his path and not the JDK. So when he typed javac it could not be found. If you have the same issue you'll need to update your PATH to point to the location of the JDK.

Comment: jdk vs jre seems to be my issue as well

Answer (score 14):

To add the paths to the **PATH** variable isn't enough. You need to add **JAVA_HOME** explicit with the path to the bin folder of the JDK, for example:

```
 JAVA_HOME -> C:\Program Files\Java\bin
```

Phonegap/Cordova is looking for the **JAVA_HOME** variable in your settings.

Comment: Should not include "\bin", As you can see in the Path, it is used like this way "%JAVA_HOME%\bin;", so you will know if you have "\bin", your path will become something like this: xxx\java\bin\bin

Answer (score 5):

set following two environment variables

```
C:\>set ANT_HOME="C:\apache-ant-1.8.4\"

C:\>set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\"
```

Answer (score 2):

set the path of javac into your PATH variable, this works for me fine, I had the same problems.
I added these three folders to the PATH variable:

```
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05;
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin;
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\lib
```

When you on the cmd in Windows, you must be able to run these commands from anywhere:

```
  javac
  java
  ant
```

When you can do this on the cmd wihtout errors, then cordova  will run.

Comment: where do you set these paths?

Answer (score 1):

Setup PhoneGap project in six easy steps.

http://wezeste.blogspot.in/201...

1. Download latest phonegap release from -> http://phonegap.com/install/
2. unzip and go to android/bin directory of downloaded phonegap zip
3. SET DIFFERENT PATHS:(you can do this in environment also)

java: set path=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin

ant: set path=%PATH%;C:\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin

JAVA_HOME: set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin

4. Create android peoject with command – create destination [package name] [project name]

create D:\AndroidProjects com.project.example hello

5. Import the android project created in eclipse
6. Download and add cordova-2.2.0.jar in lib of your project.

Run your first test application

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have done all correct, but still get this message:

```
Missing one of the following:
JDK: http://java.oracle.com
Android SDK: http://developer.android.com
...
```

The solution for me was to add all to my user variable PATH not to the System variable PATH

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that create cannot find `javac.exe`, include bin directory in the Path as well: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin` (in my case).

Answer (score 0):

I edited my system path variable and it looked like this at the end, I added lots but seems i had to coz it worked out only then

```
D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;c:\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;D:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;d:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.6\;d:\cygwin\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;D:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools;D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.0.51b\bin;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\lib;D:\SDK\apache-ant-1.8.4;D:\SDK\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin;D:\SDK\apache-ant-1.8.4\lib
```

After editing your path, you should open a new command prompt window( in windows) before you run the test "java" "ant" "adb" or "javac" commands